# Changing position of image-labels with sidesubfloat

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

My MWE currently places figures next to each other and the caption below them, as desired. However, the labels of the figures [(a) and (b)] appear to the *left* of the figures, whereas I want them to appear below the figures:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

    \usepackage{floatrow}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{c c}
            \sidesubfloat[description]{\rule{2cm}{2cm}} &
            \sidesubfloat[description]{\rule{2cm}{2cm}} \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \caption{(a) Hello (b) World}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Is there an option I can pass to `sidesubfloat` to control the position of the labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of `floatrow` the placement of subfloat captions on the left side of the corresponding subfloat is the expected behaviour:

> Another addition in floatrow for subfloats is the command, which puts subcaption label  beside  subfloat.  The  subcaption  label  always  appears  on  the  left  side.   The  key subcapbesideposition= sets vertical alignment of beside subcaption and subfloat.

To get the captions (a) and (b) underneath the images, you can use the `subfig` package, that you already load, as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \subfloat[]{\label{fig:a}\rule{2cm}{2cm}} \quad
   \subfloat[]{\label{fig:b}\rule{2cm}{2cm}}
   \caption{(a) Hello (b) World}
   \label{fig:both}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Another alternative would be using the `subcaption` package as shown in the follwing example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{2cm}
    \rule{2cm}{2cm}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{2cm}
    \rule{2cm}{2cm}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{(a) Hello (b) World}
    \label{fig:both}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To horizontally shift the subfigure captions, you can use (for the `subfig` as well as for the `subcaption` solution) the `caption` package. To change the position globally (for all images in the document) insert the following line in the preamble of your document. To change the position locally (for all subfigures in a `figure` environment) place the code inside the corresponding `figure` environment. Of course you can change the the values (in this case for left and right margin) to whatever value you like.

`\captionsetup[subfigure]{margin={2cm,0cm}}`

For a more detailed explanation on how to use the `margin` option, you can have a look at section '2.4 Margins and further paragraph options' (page 11) of the `caption` documentation

Comment: @BillyJean: I have edited my answer to include information on how to adjust the horizontal position of the captions.